# Creating XML from SQL data

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a huge XML, with over 150 element and attributes. I need to populate only a handful of them ( 5 or 6) elements with data from a  SQL server 2008 tables. This created xml need to be passed to a webservice ( to ESB)  and this has to happen on a daily schedule.

I think, it does not make sense to use XML Path here to create the XML and use SSIS. Can anyone suggest an approach?

This is the sample XML. I need just the names, address and a few ids populated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Customer.xsd">
<CustomerData>
        <StoreID></StoreID>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <Gender></Gender>
        <BirthMonth></BirthMonth>
        <BirthYear></BirthYear>
        <BirthDay></BirthDay>
        <IsEmployee></IsEmployee>
        <customerID></customerID>
        <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
        <EmailSignUp></EmailSignUp>
        <CatalogSignup></CatalogSignup>
        <Addresses>
            <BillingAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </BillingAddress>
            <CatalogSignupAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </CatalogSignupAddress>
            <StoredAddresses>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
            </StoredAddresses>
        </Addresses>
        <Hobbies_Enjoys>
            <Hobby></Hobby>
            <Enjoy></Enjoy>
        </Hobbies_Enjoys>
        <FavoriteFossilProducts>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
        </FavoriteFossilProducts>
        <AgeRange></AgeRange>
        <PreferredEmailFormat></PreferredEmailFormat>
        <SavedCreditCards>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
        </SavedCreditCards>
        <PurchasedProductList>
            <SKU></SKU>
            <SKU></SKU>
        </PurchasedProductList>
        <OrderHistory>
            <Orders>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
            </Orders>
        </OrderHistory>
        <WishLists>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
        </WishLists>
    </CustomerData>
    <CustomerData>
    </CustomerData>
</Customer>
```

Comment: can you show us an example of what needs to be created?

Comment: @ christiandev I tried using xmlpath to get the sql data in xml format. I can get the data, but putting in all the empty XML elements is proving a pain. I tried a Java Program to get the data from SQL and create the XML. IT works, but then I have to deploy the java appln separately and create a batch to run it daily. Was wondering if there are any other easier ways, esp in the MS world. Going to give @Jim V s suggestion a try.

Comment: updated qn with  sample XML

Comment: Probably the best solution is extracting directly from the tables via SELECT statement with FOR XML clause. If you need help using the FOR XML clause please post the structure of your tables and we'll help you.

Comment: @Jayvee The select is a simple select, but I need only very few values from the tables and the rest of the xml would be empty. - 
    SELECT  A1.FirstName
        ,   A1.LastName
    FROM    kc_consumer

Comment: @user1824496 - xquery FLWOR then looks like a good option as you can use the template directly and include only the values you need, I posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to take an empty version of your XML document and assign it to an NVARCHAR(MAX) variable.  For each node or parameter you wish to populate, put a "token" and use the replace function to populate the value.  For example:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = N'<Company name="~company_name~">
<Department name="~dept_name~">
<Employee name="~employee_name~" title="~employee_title~" />
</Department>
</Company>'

SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml,N'~company_name~','Microsoft')
SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml,N'~dept_name~','Executive')
SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml,N'~employee_name~','Satya Nadella')
SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml,N'~employee_title~','CEO')

SELECT CAST(@xml AS XML)
```

Here's a more traditional approach.  You'll need an arbitrary value in the cells you wish to update:

```
DECLARE @example_data TABLE 
(FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[State] CHAR(2) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @example_data
        ( FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State])
VALUES  ( 'Satya' , -- FirstName - varchar(255)
          'Nadella' , -- LastName - varchar(255)
          'M' , -- Gender - char(1)
          'Redmond' , -- City - varchar(255)
          'WA'  -- State - char(2)
        )
INSERT INTO @example_data
        ( FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State])
VALUES  ( 'Larry' , -- FirstName - varchar(255)
          'Ellison' , -- LastName - varchar(255)
          'M' , -- Gender - char(1)
          'Woodside' , -- City - varchar(255)
          'CA'  -- State - char(2)
        )


DECLARE 
@customer_xml XML,
@xml XML,
@temp NVARCHAR(255),
@FirstName VARCHAR(255),
@LastName  VARCHAR(255),
@Gender CHAR(1),
@City VARCHAR(255),
@State CHAR(2)

SET @customer_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Customer.xsd">
<CustomerData>
        <StoreID></StoreID>
        <FirstName>a</FirstName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Gender>c</Gender>
        <BirthMonth></BirthMonth>
        <BirthYear></BirthYear>
        <BirthDay></BirthDay>
        <IsEmployee></IsEmployee>
        <customerID></customerID>
        <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
        <EmailSignUp></EmailSignUp>
        <CatalogSignup></CatalogSignup>
        <Addresses>
            <BillingAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City>d</City>
                <State>e</State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </BillingAddress>
            <CatalogSignupAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </CatalogSignupAddress>
            <StoredAddresses>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
            </StoredAddresses>
        </Addresses>
        <Hobbies_Enjoys>
            <Hobby></Hobby>
            <Enjoy></Enjoy>
        </Hobbies_Enjoys>
        <FavoriteFossilProducts>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
        </FavoriteFossilProducts>
        <AgeRange></AgeRange>
        <PreferredEmailFormat></PreferredEmailFormat>
        <SavedCreditCards>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
        </SavedCreditCards>
        <PurchasedProductList>
            <SKU></SKU>
            <SKU></SKU>
        </PurchasedProductList>
        <OrderHistory>
            <Orders>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
            </Orders>
        </OrderHistory>
        <WishLists>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
        </WishLists>
    </CustomerData>
</Customer>'

DECLARE xml_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State]
FROM @example_data

OPEN xml_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @FirstName, @LastName, @Gender, @City, @State

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @xml = @customer_xml

    SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/Customer/CustomerData/FirstName[1]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@FirstName")
  ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/Customer/CustomerData/LastName[1]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@LastName")
  ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/Customer/CustomerData/Gender[1]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@Gender")
  ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/City[1]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@City")
  ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/State[1]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@State")
  ')


    select @xml

    FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @FirstName, @LastName, @Gender, @City, @State
END
```

This approach does not require a value in the nodes to be updated.  It simply inserts a new node, then deletes the old node:

```
DECLARE @example_data TABLE 
(FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[State] CHAR(2) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @example_data
        ( FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State])
VALUES  ( 'Satya' , -- FirstName - varchar(255)
          'Nadella' , -- LastName - varchar(255)
          'M' , -- Gender - char(1)
          'Redmond' , -- City - varchar(255)
          'WA'  -- State - char(2)
        )
INSERT INTO @example_data
        ( FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State])
VALUES  ( 'Larry' , -- FirstName - varchar(255)
          'Ellison' , -- LastName - varchar(255)
          'M' , -- Gender - char(1)
          'Woodside' , -- City - varchar(255)
          'CA'  -- State - char(2)
        )


DECLARE 
@customer_xml XML,
@xml XML,
@temp NVARCHAR(255),
@FirstName VARCHAR(255),
@LastName  VARCHAR(255),
@Gender CHAR(1),
@City VARCHAR(255),
@State CHAR(2)

SET @customer_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Customer.xsd">
<CustomerData>
        <StoreID></StoreID>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <Gender></Gender>
        <BirthMonth></BirthMonth>
        <BirthYear></BirthYear>
        <BirthDay></BirthDay>
        <IsEmployee></IsEmployee>
        <customerID></customerID>
        <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
        <EmailSignUp></EmailSignUp>
        <CatalogSignup></CatalogSignup>
        <Addresses>
            <BillingAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </BillingAddress>
            <CatalogSignupAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </CatalogSignupAddress>
            <StoredAddresses>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
                <StoredAddress>
                    <Address1></Address1>
                    <Address2></Address2>
                    <Address3></Address3>
                    <City></City>
                    <State></State>
                    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                    <Fax1></Fax1>
                </StoredAddress>
            </StoredAddresses>
        </Addresses>
        <Hobbies_Enjoys>
            <Hobby></Hobby>
            <Enjoy></Enjoy>
        </Hobbies_Enjoys>
        <FavoriteFossilProducts>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
        </FavoriteFossilProducts>
        <AgeRange></AgeRange>
        <PreferredEmailFormat></PreferredEmailFormat>
        <SavedCreditCards>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
            <CreditCard>
                <AcctNum></AcctNum>
                <ExpiryDate></ExpiryDate>
            </CreditCard>
        </SavedCreditCards>
        <PurchasedProductList>
            <SKU></SKU>
            <SKU></SKU>
        </PurchasedProductList>
        <OrderHistory>
            <Orders>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <Number></Number>
                    <TotalAmount></TotalAmount>
                    <Promotion></Promotion>
                    <TimePlaced></TimePlaced>
                </Order>
            </Orders>
        </OrderHistory>
        <WishLists>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
            <WishList>
                <Name></Name>
                <Description></Description>
                <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                <IsDefault></IsDefault>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Quantity></Quantity>
                        <PartNumber></PartNumber>
                        <DateCreated></DateCreated>
                        <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </WishList>
        </WishLists>
    </CustomerData>
</Customer>'

DECLARE xml_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT FirstName , LastName , Gender , City , [State]
FROM @example_data

OPEN xml_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @FirstName, @LastName, @Gender, @City, @State

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @xml = @customer_xml

    SET @xml.modify('
    insert <FirstName>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@FirstName")) }</FirstName>          
    before (/Customer/CustomerData/FirstName)[1]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    delete /Customer/CustomerData/FirstName[2]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    insert <LastName>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@LastName")) }</LastName>          
    before (/Customer/CustomerData/LastName)[1]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    delete /Customer/CustomerData/LastName[2]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    insert <Gender>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@Gender")) }</Gender>          
    before (/Customer/CustomerData/Gender)[1]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    delete /Customer/CustomerData/Gender[2]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    insert <City>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@City")) }</City>          
    before (/Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/City)[1]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    delete /Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/City[2]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    insert <State>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@State")) }</State>          
    before (/Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/State)[1]
    ')

    SET @xml.modify('
    delete /Customer/CustomerData/Addresses/BillingAddress/State[2]
    ')

    select @xml

    FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @FirstName, @LastName, @Gender, @City, @State
END
```

Comment: V - I want this in a cursor and repeatedly create the nodes.  when i try that I get an XML parsing error. This comment section would not let me copy the code in here

Comment: V's approach would work just fine. I had to split the xml a little further since replace wasn't working fine when i tried doing it together. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can also use FLWOR which will allow you to generate the xml in one go by using a template and adding data only to the elements you want.
You won't need to create tables or stored procedures. For example:

```
declare @x xml
set @x=(select FirstName, LastName from kc_consumer for xml path('CustomerData'))

SELECT @x.query('
for $a in /CustomerData
  return 
<CustomerData>
<StoreID></StoreID>

<FirstName>{data($a/FirstName)}</FirstName>
<LastName>{data($a/LastName)}</LastName>

<Gender></Gender>
<BirthMonth></BirthMonth>
<BirthYear></BirthYear>
<BirthDay></BirthDay>
<IsEmployee></IsEmployee>
<customerID></customerID>
</CustomerData>
')
```

I'm just including a few nodes for readability, you just need to paste the rest of them.

Comment: -This seem to be a simple straightforward solution. However since my data contains special characters, i get the illegal xml character error - XML parsing: line 1, character 225029, illegal xml character . I wanted to use the TYPE attribute, but it gives me more errors. Is there a way to include the TYPE attribute or get the special characters as part of the data as well?

Comment: @user1824496 - If you know which one is the character causing problems you can replace it with "&x;" excluding the quotation marks and x being the name of the char that you can find in this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @user1824496 - by replacing the character I mean for example: replace(yourcolumn,'<','&lt;')